# change document set content type default view using JSOM client side

Tags: document, document-set

I have a document set content type associated with document Library, I need to change the default view at the Welcome Page View section of this content type using jquery client side. Is it possible ? I can do this via powershell but I need client side code for this.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any code to do this. This can be achieved through the GUI.

Go to your site settings > site content types > click your custom document set content type > document set settings > under the "welcome page columns" section you can change the welcome page "view".

Comment: Submits , I am aware of that but due to some reason 'Doument set settings' is not accessible, I need client side code for that since I am creating document sets via JSOM only.